# Complex analysis, Jameson Exercise 2.1.1

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Exercise: Let $f(x + iy) = x + y$, and for $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$, define $F(z)=\int _{[0 \to z]}f$. At which points is $F$ differentiable?

Is my answer correct? Here's my answer:

$$F(z+h)-F(z)=\int _{[0 \to z+h]}f-\int _{[0 \to z]}f=\int _{[z \to z+h]}f$$

(Edit: As someone has pointed out, we cannot assume $\int _{[0 \to z]}f+\int _{[z \to z+h]}f=\int _{[0 \to z+h]}f$, so this proof is wrong but will still be left here for your reference of possible mistakes)

Let $z=z_1+iz_2, h=h_1+ih_2$, parameterise $[z \to z+h]$ by $\gamma (t)=z+th$ where $t\in [0,1]$, then

$$\int _{[z \to z+h]}f=\int _{[z \to z+h]}(x+y)=\int_{0}^{1}(z_1+z_2+t(h_1+h_2))h dt$$

$$=h\left[(z_1+z_2)t+(h_1+h_2)\frac{t^2}{2}\right]^{1}_{0}=h[(z_1+z_2)+(h_1+h_2)/2]$$

So $$\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h}=(z_1+z_2)+(h_1+h_2)/2\overset{h\to0}{\rightarrow}(z_1+z_2)$$

In particular, $F$ is differentiable at all points.

Also, if my answer is correct, can it be shorten? $f$ is not differentiable so I guess I can't use Cauchy's Theorem. Although $f$ is continuous, I don't think $\int_{\partial T} f=0$ for all triangle $T$, so I can't use that to say $F$ is differentiable.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: why is $\int _{[0 \to z+h]}f-\int _{[0 \to z]}f=\int _{[z \to z+h]}f$ true?? In general $0, z, z+h$ form a triangle as $z+h$ is not collinear with $z$, so that being true would imply that the integral of $f$ on a triangle is zero etc

Comment: @Conrad Thanks, my mistake. I think $\int Re(z)$ on triangle $(0, 1+i, -1+i)$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: @Conrad By the way, may I ask what's the common practice of posters on Stack Exchange after posting a wrong answer?

Comment: Just add a note of why what you thought is incorrect

Comment: @Conrad Thanks a lot!

Comment: happy to be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$. We parametrize the curve as $\gamma(t) = t(x+iy),~~t\in[0,1]$. Then the function $F(z)$ becoems
$$F(z) =\int_{0}^{1} t(x+y)(x+iy)dt =C(x+y)(x+iy):=u(x,y) + iv(x,y).$$
Determine at which point the function is not differentiable by the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thanks, if I'm correct, the only point where it's differentiable is 0 right?

Comment: $0$ is a correct guess. But the Cauchy-Riemann equations are only necessary conditions for complex differentiability so you need check sufficient conditions or  just show that the limit in the definition of differentiability exists.